# f2py does not find any compiler

Tags: python, f2py

I have the NAG Fortran compiler installed. I can compile Fortran code by calling `nagfor -o helloworld helloworld.f90`. If I run f2py with `f2py -c -m helloworld helloworld.f90 --fcompiler=nagfor` nothing happens. Additionally, if I just run `f2py` nothing happens. `f2py --help-fcompiler` gives no output.

I have Windows 7 installed and use the the Anaconda Python distribution. Any idea how I should address this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Following Ian`s comments and [this post](http://scientificcomputingco.blogspot.com.au/2013/02/f2py-on-64bit-windows-python27.html) I managed to run f2py (unfortunately only with the GNU Fortran compiler).

I had to change line 337 in `C:\Loopy\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\gnu.py` to:

```
pass #raise NotImplementedError("Only MS compiler supported with gfortran on win64")
```

Additionally I use `C:\Loopy\Scripts\f2py.py`.

Answer (score 0):

It's unusual that you aren't seeing any error output at all.
That makes it sound like you're calling something else.
Make sure Anaconda's scripts directory on your path and that you don't have some sort of script in your current directory called `f2py`.
Depending on how you have your computer is set up to interpret file types, you may need to run something like `python f2py.py` with the rest of the arguments the same.

If you're using Anaconda, you should already have a copy of gfortran intsalled too.
If you want to use that instead, make sure Anaconda's bin directory is on your path.
Unless you have a very recent (1.10, currently in development) version of numpy, to use gfortran, you'll need to go to `Anaconda/Lib/site-packages/numpy/distutils/fcompiler/gnu.py` and comment out the lines (somewhere around line 330) that raise an error if you're on 64 bit windows.
Once you've done that, it should work fine.

Edit: judging by the old [f2py docs](https://sysbio.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/usersguide/#scipy-distutils-0-2-2-and-up) and the [current source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4cbced22a8306d7214a4e18d12e651c034143922/numpy/distutils/fcompiler/nag.py), the proper `fcompiler` flag is `--fcompiler=nag`.
The compiler is specified by vendor, not by executable name.

Comment: I added .py to PATHEXT so that is not the problem. I have the folders: C:\Loopy and C:\Loopy\Scripts in my path. If i do `import f2py` in an ipyton shell, i do see an output describing the usage of f2py. However, i am using f2py in a command shell. That is the correct usage, right ?

Comment: @Moritz That's the right way to use it. Do you see anything at all when you run `f2py` or `python f2py.py`? Is there any error of any sort? What to you get when you run `where f2py` (or `which f2py` in a shell terminal)?

Comment: @Moritz I also just updated the answer to include a suggestion about how to use the `fcompiler` flag.

Comment: If i run `where f2py` I get `C:\Loopy\Scripts\f2py.py` but if I run `python f2py.py` I get `python: can't open file 'f2py.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. If I run `python f2py.py` in the directory `C:\Loopy\Scripts` i get the expected help message

Comment: @Moritz Have you restarted all the terminals you're running these commands in? If f2py is on your path python should be able to see it, but changes to the path don't take effect till you restart your terminal. Two possible workarounds for now would be to set python files to be run by python by default (right click on a python file, mouse over "open with", then click "choose default program") or to specify the full path (i.e. run `python C:\Loopy\Scripts\f2py.py` with the rest of the arguments) when running f2py.

Comment: After writing  `pass #raise NotImplementedError("Only MS compiler supported with gfortran on win64")` in line 337 in `C:\Loopy\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\gnu.py` and following your workaround, i can at least see that f2py does not find the NAG compiler (`python C:\Loopy\Scripts\f2py.py -c --help-fcompiler`)

Comment: Hmmmm. Looking at the output of `f2py -c --help-fcompiler` it looks like the nag compiler isn't supported on windows. You can try seeing if it will work anyway by modifying the source files of f2py. That's risky business though. You'll have to start by opening `numpy/distutils/fcompiler/__init__.py` and add `"nag"` to the default compilers for win32 and cygwin, then try it again and go from there. You may need to start changing the flags in `numpy/distutils/fcompiler/nag.py` as well. From here I really don't know how to help without having the compiler installed myself. Can you use gfortran?

Comment: Okay, I see that you got gfortran working. I'm glad this helped.